# Script not creating <a> element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to add a link to a page I cannot directly access the HTML on, aside from the footer. Using Javascript, I am attempting to use the `createElement()` method. I have successfully used the same process to create a `link` element in the header.

```
function createForgotPasswordLink(){
    var pwlink=document.createElement("a")
    pwlink.setAttribute("id", "forgotPssLink")
    pwlink.setAttribute("href", "http://www.mysite.com/page.aspx")
    pwlink.innerHTML("Forgot Password?")
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(pwlink)
}
createForgotPasswordLink();
```

The only difference between the two scripts is that when making the `link` element, I `appendChild()` on the `head` not `body` and I do not set the `innerHTML` of the `link` element as I have done in the above `a` element. For some reason, the above code does not work. Even after removing line 5.

Comment: What errors do you get? Has the body loaded yet?

Comment: Do alert(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) output Object?

Comment: `innerHTML` isn't a function. Set it with `=`. I'm not sure why the two answers that said so were deleted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the property `.innerHTML` like a method.  Don't use parens, use an `=`.  Also, I wouldn't bother setting the attributes, just set the property values directly.  The code is more straightforward and easier to read:

```
function createForgotPasswordLink() {
    var pwlink = document.createElement("a");
    pwlink.id = "forgotPssLink";
    pwlink.href = "http://www.mysite.com/page.aspx";
    pwlink.innerHTML = "Forgot Password?";
    document.body.appendChild(pwlink)
}
```

Comment: At the end of the original post, I mentioned that I had tried running the same code sans line 5. I didn't think my `innherHTML` usage was correct to begin with. Unfortunately, you suggestions did not work. Taking the adivce of one of the other commentors, I ran alert on the `document.body` and it printed `null`. Would it help if I put my HTML markup in the OP? Its a pretty basic biolerplate html 5 template, but I will put it on if needed.

Comment: Moving the script to an external document did the trick. Used the same code you provided. Thanks.